# VB.NET Using Trackbar to Re-Locate Text in Bitmap?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to make the user able to freely drag text around a bitmap with a trackbar, heres my attempt but as you can see when the trackbar is dragged the text doesn't move instead it creates a new layer of text. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, any help is appreciated!

[Result of my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2NYu.png)

```
    Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged, TrackBarX.Scroll, TrackBarY.Scroll

    MaskedTextBoxX.Text = TrackBarX.Value
    MaskedTextBoxY.Text = TrackBarY.Value

    If Not PictureBox.Image Is Nothing Then

        Dim bmp As Bitmap
        bmp = Form3.PictureBox1.Image

        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        gr.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        Dim f As New Font("Impact", 72)
        Dim b As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
        Dim gp As New GraphicsPath

        gp.AddString(MaskedTextBox1.Text, f.FontFamily, FontStyle.Regular, 100, New Point(TrackBarX.Value, TrackBarY.Value), StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
        gr.FillPath(Brushes.White, gp)
        gr.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gp)
        gp.Dispose()
        gr.Dispose()

        PictureBox.Image = bmp
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to store the original image somewhere, and when you draw the text create a clone of the original image, draw the text there and present the new clone. Another way is to create a picture box inside a panel, set the image as background to the panel, make the picture box transparent, and each time you draw text you create a new transparent bitmap, draw the text and set it as Image to the picturebox, in this way the transparent image will be overlayed on the background without cloning it each time.

Comment: As you can see I'm trying to store the image in a separate form(form3) which is hidden, idk why its not working

Comment: What im trying to do is each time the trackbar value changes it creates a bitmap with the original image stored in form3 but apparently thats not the way to go

Comment: Because you aren't cloning it. When you do `bmp = Form3.PictureBox1.Image` means that bmp and Image share the same instance of the image. Any change done to Image will be reflected in bmp as they are the same instance.

Comment: i see, thx for the help

Comment: use `bmp = New Bitmap(Form3.PictureBox1.Image)` that will create a copy of the image.

Comment: Fixed it, its simpler than I thought, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments

```
bmp = New Bitmap(Form3.PictureBox1.Image)
```